# Advance search using dropdown list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I an doing an advance search code .. I have 6 drop-down lists , the user can choose one or more value from one or all the drop downs or choose the "-" value which means no value selected .. My code is working and the result is the union of all the values .. how can I find only the intersect ?

I mean if I choose (Asia) from the first drop-down and (Arabic) from the second ,, my result is all the countries in Asia and all the countries that have Arabic language..
how can I have only the Asian countries that talks Arabic >> the intersect ?

```
if (!Class1.Search_Continent.Equals("-"))//DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        {
            sunc.conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select Country_name FROM Country WHERE Continent_name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", sunc.conn);
            SqlDataReader dr1;
            dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr1.Read())
            {DropDownList9.Items.Add(dr1["Country_name"].ToString());}
            sunc.conn.Close();

            if (!Class1.Search_Country.Equals("-"))//DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString();
            {
                RemoveDuplicateItems(DropDownList9);
                sunc.conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select Country_name FROM Country WHERE Country_name='" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "'", sunc.conn);
                SqlDataReader dr2;
                dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {DropDownList9.Items.Add(dr2["Country_name"].ToString());}
                sunc.conn.Close();

                if (!Class1.Search_City.Equals("-"))//DropDownList3.SelectedValue.ToString();
                {
                    RemoveDuplicateItems(DropDownList9);
                    sunc.conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("Select Country_name FROM City WHERE City_name='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "'", sunc.conn);
                    SqlDataReader dr3;
                    dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

                    while (dr3.Read())
                    {
                        DropDownList9.Items.Add(dr3["Country_name"].ToString());
                    }

                    //dr3.Close();
                    //conn3.Close();
                    sunc.conn.Close();
                    if (!Class1.Search_Religion.Equals("-"))//DropDownList4.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    {
                        RemoveDuplicateItems(DropDownList9);
                        //SqlConnection conn4 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AK-PC\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True");
                        //conn4.Open();
                        sunc.conn.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("Select Country_name FROM Religion WHERE Religion_name='" + DropDownList4.SelectedValue + "'", sunc.conn);
                        SqlDataReader dr4;
                        dr4 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();

                        while (dr4.Read())
                        {
                            DropDownList9.Items.Add(dr4["Country_name"].ToString());
                        }

                        //dr4.Close();
                        //conn4.Close();
                        sunc.conn.Close();
                        if (!Class1.Search_Type.Equals("-"))//DropDownList5.SelectedValue.ToString();
                        {
                            RemoveDuplicateItems(DropDownList9);
                            //SqlConnection conn5 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AK-PC\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True");
                            //conn5.Open();
                            sunc.conn.Open();
                            SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("Select Country_name FROM Country WHERE Type_of_government='" + DropDownList5.SelectedValue + "'", sunc.conn);
                            SqlDataReader dr5;
                            dr5 = cmd5.ExecuteReader();

                            while (dr5.Read())
                            {
                                DropDownList9.Items.Add(dr5["Country_name"].ToString());
                            }

                            //dr5.Close();
                            //conn5.Close();
                            sunc.conn.Close();
                            if (!Class1.Search_Language.Equals("-"))//DropDownList6.SelectedValue.ToString();
                            {
                                RemoveDuplicateItems(DropDownList9);
                                //SqlConnection conn6 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=AK-PC\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True");
                                //conn6.Open();
                                sunc.conn.Open();
                                SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("Select Country_name FROM Language WHERE Language_name='" + DropDownList6.SelectedValue + "'", sunc.conn);
                                SqlDataReader dr6;
                                dr6 = cmd6.ExecuteReader();

                                while (dr6.Read())
                                {
                                    DropDownList9.Items.Add(dr6["Country_name"].ToString());
                                }

                                //dr6.Close();
                                //conn6.Close();
                                sunc.conn.Close();

                                if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Equals("-") && DropDownList2.SelectedValue.Equals("-") &&
                                    DropDownList3.SelectedValue.Equals("-") && DropDownList4.SelectedValue.Equals("-") &&
                                    DropDownList5.SelectedValue.Equals("-") && DropDownList6.SelectedValue.Equals("-"))
                                {
                                    Button2.Enabled = false;
                                    Label1.Text = "you have to choose from the dropdown list";
                                }
                                else if (DropDownList9.SelectedValue.Equals("-"))
                                {
                                    Button2.Enabled = false;
                                    Label1.Text = "No result ";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: all I can say is, I'm glad I don't have to maintain that ;)

Comment: sounds like you need to refactor that code and perhaps create a Stored Procedure and you will need to have some Where Clauses you have filtering but you need to build that query based on all the options at the end not one at a time

Answer (score 2):

I would alter your code so that it creates one query based on the different options, then returns just the result of that query.

For example:

```
string query = "Select Country_name FROM Country WHERE Continent_name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'";
if (!Class1.Search_Country.Equals("-"))
   query+= " and Country_name='" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "'";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, sunc.conn);
```

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you want to do this in a single query like:

```
SELECT Country_Name
FROM Country C
    INNER JOIN City CTY on (CTY.Country_Name = C.Country_Name)
    INNER JOIN Religion R on (R.Country_Name = C.Country_Name
WHERE ((@City ='') or (CTY.City_Name = @City))
  AND ((@Religion ='') or (R.Religion_Name = @Religion))
  AND ((@Government = '') or (C.Type_of_Government = @Government))
```

You would then pass @City, @Religion and @Government as parameters to the query.  If any individual parameter is passed in then the WHERE clause would filter on it; or ignore if that parameter was blank.

Comment: @user1915452:  That's SQL code...  you use it as the command, then add parameters to the command object as necessary

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the query something like below.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select Country_name FROM Country WHERE (Continent_name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' or Continent_name=Continent_name) AND (Country_name='" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "' OR Country_name=Country_name) AND (City_name='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "' OR City_name=City_name) AND (Religion_name='" + DropDownList4.SelectedValue + "' OR Religion_name=Religion_name) AND (Type_of_government='" + DropDownList5.SelectedValue + "' OR Type_of_government=Type_of_government) AND (Language_name='" + DropDownList6.SelectedValue + "' OR Language_name=Language_name)", sunc.conn);
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: but , what if the user leave some of the dropdown list without selecting a value ?